# Локальный сервер OpenServer ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: openserver

При запуске сайта на локальном сервере выбрасывает ошибку про большое количество переадресаций (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS). За день до этого всё было в порядке.

**.htaccess**

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect all https traffic to http, unless it is pointed at /liqpay_reps.php
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/liqpay_response\.php$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://i-shop.local/ [R=301,L]

# redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://i-shop.local/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.i-shop\.local [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://i-shop.local$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://i-shop.local [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://i-shop.local [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^product_reviews_write\.php\/info\/p(.*)_.*\.html product_reviews_write\.php\?products_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product_reviews_write\.php\/action\/process\/info\/p([0-9]*)_.*\.html product_reviews_write\.php\?action=process\&products_id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^product_info\.php\/info\/p(.*)_.*\/action\/add_product product_info\.php\?products_id=$1\&action=add_product\ [L]
RewriteRule ^shopping_cart\.php\/products_id\/([0-9]*)\/info\/p([0-9]*)_.*\.html shopping_cart\.php\?products_id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(product_info|index|shop_content|news|faq|articles|article_info).php(.*)$ redirector.php [L]

RewriteRule ^.*\.gif|\.jpg|\.png|\.css|\.php|\.js$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*).html(.*)$ manager.php [L]

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
php_value register_globals                0
php_value session.auto_start              0
php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
php_value default_charset UTF-8
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>    

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

---

**Nginx запросы**

```
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:29 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:30 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:30 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
i-shop.local: 127.0.0.1 [20/Feb/2023:11:51:30 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 229 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: комментируете половину правил, проверяете. и так далее. называется «метод половинного деления». у вас и этого не получается?

Comment: Проект для меня новый, только знакомлюсь с ним. Проблема в том, что день назад не было жалоб на переадресации.